# Use React Router alongside Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

> - /api/* handled by Express.js
> - anything else handled by the React Router Dom

I've created my application using create-react-app and ejected. For some reason, my express server isn't working as intended:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")));
});
```

When I do `yarn build` (which executes `node scripts/build.js` came by default with create-react-app) it build my application, then I start the express server and navigate to it and it just appears a blank page with the console outputting:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/static/css/main.766345d1.css".
>
> main.936d1f48.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

That happens when I have my `homepage` property unset in `package.json`.

When I set it to `./` this happens:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:3000/static/css/main.766345d1.css".
>
> manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
>
> main.5e4ef579.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Apparently any call is redirected to return `index.html`. What can I do?

*Pst. I'm a beginner with react-router and especially express.js.*

EDIT: If it helps, here is my `build` directory structure:
[image]

Also, please note that I am running the application by building and then just starting the express server, even tho I'm not sure if that's how it supposed to be.

Comment: Looks like the path you have in `index.html` to your JS file isn't correct (or the JS file doesn't exist).

Comment: I had this error before It's a pathing issue your CSS file that you're trying to point to isn't correct. How I fixed this last time was I pasted my localhost address to where my css file was in the url until I found it. Once I found it, I adjusted the path to where it pointed to and it fixed it.

Comment: I am not setting my paths, they by default with create-react-app, it should work by default... Also I updated the post, I'm not sure if the homepage property is how u change the path.

Comment: You want everything to redirect to index in an SPA, but not the assets of course. Keep the wildcard-route and mount your folder using [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) *before* the wildcard-route. everything not found in your static folder will be caught and redirected to index.

Comment: I did what you said @ippi and it still shows the same error, here are my changes: 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "../build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")));
});

Comment: It turns out that "express.static(__dirname + "../build")" was the problem, the path wasn't been property put together, so I used path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "../build")) and it worked. Also your comment worked, thanks!